# What is this error message which appeared after i've run the program?

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBnqQ.jpg)I press the run button, it runs successfully, but this message has started showing. What does it mean?
I've recently updated the dart sdk, which caused some problems but i've solved them, but I still don;t understand why is this error message appearing.

Comment: Hi, could you provide a bit more information (in text form)? Like what is the error message and include the output of `flutter doctor`.

Comment: i've added the picture in the post now, please have a look

Comment: This is not an error message, but a warning, that you are using deprecated stuff, did you follow the instructions in the article?

Comment: no i didnt, but before upgrading my dart sdk, it didn't show this warning. Is it important though?

Comment: 'Deprecated' means that in a future release, some code that you are using will be removed. You should follow the instructions from the link to use the new approach.